# How to apply perl range operator on input from <STDIN>?

Tags: perl

I'm not able to apply perl range operator over an input taken from Standard Input. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@range = (1..5, 6, 7, 8..10);
print "@range\n";

print "Enter your range. Esc by CTRL+D.\n";
chomp(@user_range = <STDIN>); # input 1..5<LF> 6<LF> 7..10<LF> CTRL+D
print "@user_range\n";
```

The **first block of code (@range) works fine** and **outputs: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;**
In the **second (@user_range)** I **input 1..5 6 7..10 CTRL+D**. The **output I get is 1..5 6 7..10** **instead of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.**

Please help.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything you read from `STDIN` or any other filehandle comes in as just a string. This is a basic security measure, you don't want your programming language evaluating input as code.

You could run it through `eval`, but that's a security hole; it lets users run arbitrary code. ***Don't use `eval STRING`*** unless you know what you're doing. `eval BLOCK` is fine, it's totally different.

Instead, if you want something done to input you'll have to do it yourself. If it's just simple numbers, then it can be fairly straightforward.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Read the string from input and remove the newline.
my $list_string = <STDIN>;
chomp $list_string;

# Split it into a list on commas.
# "1..5, 6, 7..10" becomes "1..5", "6", "7..10".
my @list = split /\s*,\s*/, $list_string;

# Go through each element checking for a range operator.
# If there's a range operator, replace it with the range.
# Otherwise leave it alone.
@list = map { range_transform($_) } @list;

print join ", ", @list;

sub range_transform {
    my $string = shift;

    # Match the X..Y. If it doesn't match, just return it.
    return $string unless $string =~ m{^(\d+)\.\.(\d+)$};

    # Perform the range operation.
    return $1..$2;   
}
```

This doesn't have any error checking, it should probably also check that the input is either a number OR a range operator and puke if it's anything else. But that should get you started.

Comment: This is very helpful. I understand why one shouldn't be using eval on STDIN without proper safeguards. I just have to work with numbers for now, your subroutine will work.

Comment: @circuit.maker If you need to work with something more complicated, [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) might be useful.